# Controlling SerializerSettings for ASP.Net Core 2.0 returning IActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I've created an ASP.NET 2.0 webapi and am trying to return an abstract type from a method which returns IActionResult, i.e.

```
    // GET api/trades/5
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetTrade")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Trade), 200)] 
    [ProducesResponseType(404)]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var item = _context.Trades.FirstOrDefault(trade => trade.Id == id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(item);
    }
```

The Trade type is an abstract base class, I want the serialised JSON to include the $type attribute so the client can deserialise to the correct concrete type. The code below controls the output serialiser if I change the method to return Trade (the json returned contains a $type attribute with the concrete type name) but not IActionResult (no $type attribute).

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddDbContext<RiskSystemDbContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("RiskSystemDb"));

        services
            .AddMvc(options => {})
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
                options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                options.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
            });
    }
```

How do I set TypeNameHandling for an IActionResult?

Edit:

For a class FutureTrade : Trade {} I expect

```
{
  "$type": "RiskSystem.Model.FutureTrade, RiskSystem.Model",
  "id": 1,
  "createdDateTime": "2018-04-12T15:59:11.3680885+12:00"
  ...
}
```

Getting

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "createdDateTime": "2018-04-12T15:59:11.3680885+12:00"
  ...
}
```

The following works as expected

```
    // GET api/trades
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Trade> Get()
    {
        return _context.Trades.ToList();
    }
```

Regards
Dave

Comment: Please include some expected and actual json object structure that is returned to your JS client. This will help everyone to visualize your issue.

Comment: I've edited as requested (the client is .Net not JS though)

Comment: Can you try with this option `options.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects`

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work consistently. Add as a proper solution and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @user2981639 by default web api uses JSON.NET serializer settings as `TypeNameHandling.None` so the $type is not included, you can change it as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks @Niladri, I was aware that TypeNameHandling added the $type but the behavior of TypeNameHandling.Auto isn't consistent between returning a DTO or returning an IActionResult, as Thangadurai mentioned using TypeNameHandling.Objects works in both cases

Comment: @Thangadurai please post as an answer so I can give you the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the TypeNameHandling from `Auto` to `Objects` will force the JSON serializer to emit the type name always.

Please change your TypeNameHandling from

```
options.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
```

to

```
options.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
```